# Jquery UI datepicker stops working in meteor if you use it in two different layouts

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, meteor, jquery-ui-datepicker, meteor-blaze

I am not sure how to get around this or if this is a bug in meteor but if I have a template that appears under two different layouts (I use iron router)

This code for datepicker

```
Template.new_event.rendered = function (){
 this.$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
 });
}
```

does not work. If I land on a page that uses the "new_event" template and it is using a different layout from the one that last used the "new_event" template the datepicker command does not trigger and no errors are posted. Also I have tried using different templates (doing rendered calls on different templates), but once I go to a page that calls "datepicker" and go to another page that calls "datepicker" it does not trigger if the page is a different layout

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the input conditionally rendered in one case and not in the other?

Comment: @DavidWeldon no it is not, The input is always rendered

Answer (score 0):

Just try removing `this` from your code:

```
Template.new_event.rendered = function (){
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
}
```

The idea is that whatever `this` is referring to might not be where when you use a different layout.

Comment: No that does not work, I just tried it. Also "this" precedes Jquery functions in meteor in the rendered function

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to download the meteor Datetimepicker package.

```
meteor add ryanswapp:datetime-picker
```

this could would solve ur problem I suppose:

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function() {
   $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      format: 'Y-m-d',
      timepicker: false
   })  
});
```

Your HTML should look like this

```
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="datetimepicker" placeholder="Enter the time">
```

Hope this helps!